# Itens em javascript desaparecem ao fazer postback da página

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp

Estou a fazer um website e copiei para o meu projecto um calendário. O calendário está aqui: https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview 
no separador calendário. Tenho tudo feito como está lá e consigo criar os eventos e arrastar para cima do calendário. O que me acontece é que quando faço postback da página o que criei como evento e onde o coloquei no calendário desaparecem. 
Alguém me ajuda a guardar os eventos criados?

Comment: Ola, Acho que o constragimento deve estar no postback e não no calendario. Acho para conseguirem ajudar necessita colocar o codigo do postback.

Comment: viva, o postback é feito quando mudo de página ou pressiono F5. Não há código no postback @TiagoGomes

Comment: Mas tem codigo na função Page_Load?

Comment: Não @TiagoGomes

Comment: É necessário então alguem que saiba mais de asp. Porquê é que faz um postback?

Comment: porque mudo de menu ou vou para outra página e volto para aquela página e o que eu criei desaparece

Comment: Mas faz postback ou muda de pagina? se muda de pagina tem de guardar a informação e todas as vezes que abre a pagina tem ver se tiver dados preenche.

Comment: Muda de página e de menus... e como é que eu faço para guardar esses dados?

Comment: Existe varia formas de o fazer. Dependendo do que pretende.

Comment: Pode usar o postback para gravar a informação na sessão ou gravar na base dados.

Comment: O postback é como fosse ajax, não carrega a pagina toda outra vez. (Não sou a pessoa mais apropriada para explicar :D)

Comment: e como é que eu faço isso?